# PowerEdge T610 H700 controller upgrade

Tags: linux, raid, hardware, mdadm

I have a PowerEdge T610 server with Perc H700 RAID controller.
I wanna use the controller for non-raid, but I read some posts and the H700 controller doesn't support the non-raid operation. The problem is the Debian (yes, I know this OS not supported, but it will be works fine) installer can't detect the physical drives. So I need to create a virtual volume but I wanna use software RAID (MDADM).

On Dell drivers page I saw a Dell 6Gbps SAS HBA Firmware [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=K161K).)
Can I use this driver for H700? Or I must buy another controller which is supports non-raid? Or any controller flasing method?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Dell PERCs really are rebranded LSI gear which can often flashed with non-RAID (IT) firmware, but I don't know if the one you linked really is appropriate for your H700 controller.

That said, passing the raw devices to the OS should be only useful when using something as ZFS, whose native RAID implementation offers additional features versus HW RAID capabilities.

Linux MDRAID, while fast and versatile, is going to be slower than H700's HW RAID, due to the latter powerloss protected writeback cache. So my advice is to stick with HW RAID in this case.

If you **really** want to use MDRAID, you can create multiple 1-disk RAID0 sets, using them as the underlying devices for a Linux software RAID array.

Answer (score 0):

The firmware you linked is really only that, a firmware update. What it means is that the server will be able to work with 6gb/s sas HBA card (it really is the name of the card). If you want to use your disk with the server you have now, you will need to make raids with the card already installed, then your OS will see the disks.

Considering you have a Dell machine, I would not see the benefit of doing a software raid as the h700 is already a good hardware option. As shodanshok said you could always make multiple raids and use those for your software raid (but from what I've read it's not good to mix software and hardware raids, never tested though).

Also, though this has nothing to do with the raid configuration, why would debian not be supported ?